# how to populate a dropdown box in a edit form in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

UPDATE TO Below:

I changed the code a bit and am having a bit of success but I am still off on one thing. I changed the line

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[brokername]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
<?php } ?> </select>
```

Now it shows the correct select name and actually saves a changed value in the database however, instead of saving the name id number, it saves the actual name. a print_r of $row gives me:

Array ( [0] => 4 [id] => 4 [1] => 6 [brokername] => 6 [2] => Kims Boat [boatname] => Kims Boat )

The correct brokerlist.id for that selected user is 6 but instead of saving 6 to the boatlist.name it save the brokerlist.name field instead of the brokerlist.id.

What can I change to have it save the brokerlist.id as opposed to the physical name? :)

Thank you in advance!

(here is the new edit page code just in case:

```
<?php

    include_once('db.php');     

    if(isset($_GET['edit']))

    {

    $id = $_GET['edit']; 

    $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boatlist WHERE id='$id'"); 

    $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);   

    $brokerlistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brokerlist");

    print_r($row);

    }


    if( isset($_POST['newbrokername']) && isset($_POST['newboatname']))    
       {    
         $newbrokername = $_POST['newbrokername'];
         $newboatname = $_POST['newboatname'];     
         $id= $_POST['id'];

         $sql = "UPDATE boatlist SET brokername='$newbrokername', boatname='$newboatname' WHERE id='$id'";

         $res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());

         echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=testaddboat.php'>";

    }



?>

<table class="centerwithroom">    
<form action="testeditboat.php" method="POST">    
<tr>    
<td>New Broker Name </td><td>
<select name='newbrokername'>
  <?php
    while ($brokerlistrow = mysql_fetch_array($brokerlistquery)) {
  ?>
<option value="<?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
<?php } ?> </select>
</td>

<tr>
<td>Boat Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="newboatname" value="<?php echo $row[boatname]; ?>"/></td>
</tr>    

</tr>

<td></td><td><input type="submit" value=" Update "/></td>

</tr>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[id]; ?>"/>    

</form>
</table>
```

---

(ORIG POST Starts Here)

This is my first post and I will try to be as thorough as possible. This is just a rudimentary form and I have not added any security in it at all as I am just trying to make it work, then get to the rest :) Being new to programming my code may look bad to some of you experts and I would love any examples you could give.

On to the project. I have two mysql tables, one called brokerlist with two fields id and name. the second table is called boatlist with three fields id, brokername, and boatname. The brokername field contains the value of the brokerlist.id field and a text entered boatname.

I have created php add forms to add data to both tables that are working properly. I have created a php edit form to edit the brokerlist table that works properly. My problem lies in the form I call testeditboat.php. What I am trying to do is allow the user to change the field brokername in the testeditboat.php form with a dropdown box that populates from the mysql table brokerlist but also uses the select selected of the current entry.

Where my form currently stands is it submits the request and will change any value in the boatname field, but will not update the brokername field.

Thank you all in advance very much for your help, I hope I have been descriptive enough.

The code for my testeditboat.php form is as follows:

```
<?php

    include_once('db.php');     

    if(isset($_GET['edit']))

    {

    $id = $_GET['edit'];    
    $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boatlist WHERE id='$id'");    
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);   
    $brokerlistquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brokerlist");

    }


    if( isset($_POST['newbrokername']) && isset($_POST['newboatname']))    
       {    
         $newbrokername = $_POST['newbrokername'];
         $newboatname = $_POST['newboatname'];     
         $id= $_POST['id'];

         $sql = "UPDATE boatlist SET brokername='$newbrokername', boatname='$newboatname' WHERE id='$id'";

         $res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());

         echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=testaddboat.php'>";

    }



?>

<table class="centerwithroom">    
<form action="testeditboat.php" method="POST">    
<tr>    
<td>New Broker Name </td><td>
<select name='newbrokername'>
  <?php
    while ($brokerlistrow = mysql_fetch_array($brokerlistquery)) {
  ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row[brokername]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
<?php } ?> </select>
</td>

<tr>
<td>Boat Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="newboatname" value="<?php echo $row[boatname]; ?>"/></td>
</tr>    

</tr>

<td></td><td><input type="submit" value=" Update "/></td>

</tr>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[id]; ?>"/>    

</form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by changing the row to

```
<option value="<?php echo $brokerlistrow[id]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
<?php } ?> </select>
```

it now saved the correct value and shows the correct focus in the edit dropdown box.

Thank you all for your guidance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
$row= mysql_fetch_assoc($res); //this fetches the array in associative mode
```

Change the following line:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[brokername]; ?>" <?php if ($row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[name]) { echo selected; } ?> ><?php echo $brokerlistrow[name]; ?></option>
```

You where comparing `$row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[id]` which seems to be incorrect. You have to compare `$row[brokername] == $brokerlistrow[name]`

**Note: Stop using mysql_* extensions use mysqli_ instead***

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried changing both. When I change the id to name it loses the select selected focus and just shows the first name in the list instead of what was in the database. Also, the field still won't update even though the boat name field will update. 

Thank you for all your suggestions :) Anything else we can try?

Comment: what are the values of `$row[brokername]` and `$brokerlistrow[id]` ?

Comment: also what is the value of `print_r($row)` ?